# Tab system with pure CSS, anchor avoids the propagation to label

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm making a tab system only with CSS using `:target` and `:checked` pseudoclasses, but I have an anchor inside the label, and the label doesn't trigger the `:checked`.

If you click in the anchor, the `:checked` doesn't trigger because the click is in the `<a>` tag, but is inside a `<label>` that must trigger the radio button. If you click on the border of the tab, you'll see how it triggers the `:checked`, but not the anchor, so the `:target` can't be triggered.

Here you are my code, more understandable than the words:

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.tabs {
  position: relative;
}
input {
  display: none;
}
.tabs .tab label {
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 2px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.tabs .tab input:checked + label {
  background-color: white;
  border-bottom: 0;
  padding: 4px 2px;
  top: 1px;
}
.contents {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
}
.contents .content {
  display: none;
  padding: 20px;
}
.contents .content:target {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
  <span class="tab">
    <input type="radio" name="ch" id="check1">
    <label for="check1">
      <a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a>
    </label>
  </span>
  <span class="tab">
    <input type="radio" name="ch" id="check2">
    <label for="check2">
      <a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a>
    </label>
  </span>
  <span class="tab">
    <input type="radio" name="ch" id="check3">
    <label for="check3">
      <a href="#tab3">Tab 3</a>
    </label>
  </span>
</div>
<div class="contents">
  <div class="content" id="tab1">Contenido 1</div>
  <div class="content" id="tab2"><strong>Contenido 2</strong></div>
  <div class="content" id="tab3"><em>Contenido 3</em></div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to combine `:checked` and `:target` pseudoclasses to achieve a complete tab system only with CSS?

Thank you.

### EDIT

Here you are the snippet without anchor. Obviously the `:target` will not be triggered:

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.tabs {
  position: relative;
}
input {
  display: none;
}
.tabs .tab label {
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 2px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.tabs .tab input:checked + label {
  background-color: white;
  border-bottom: 0;
  padding: 4px 2px;
  top: 1px;
}
.contents {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
}
.contents .content {
  display: none;
  padding: 20px;
}
.contents .content:target {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
  <span class="tab">
    <input type="radio" name="ch" id="check1">
    <label for="check1">
      Tab 1
    </label>
  </span>
  <span class="tab">
    <input type="radio" name="ch" id="check2">
    <label for="check2">
      Tab 2
    </label>
  </span>
  <span class="tab">
    <input type="radio" name="ch" id="check3">
    <label for="check3">
      Tab 3
    </label>
  </span>
</div>
<div class="contents">
  <div class="content" id="tab1">Contenido 1</div>
  <div class="content" id="tab2"><strong>Contenido 2</strong></div>
  <div class="content" id="tab3"><em>Contenido 3</em></div>
</div>
```

Comment: An very old relative Mozila bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=19983. They said that this was fixed.. Apparently, not.

Comment: That bug is not related. The link inside the label works, but the radio button is not checked clicking in the link that have a label. Without the link, the radio button is checked. It fails in Chrome too.

Comment: I am open to other alternatives using only CSS, if someone have an idea.

Comment: http://codepen.io/oknoblich/pen/tfjFl I think this is the best aproach, element siblings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `input:checked`, `:target` is not efficient cause this event is not triggered at all.

You need to put your `input` **ahead** in the flow so you can use the selector `~` to select any sibblings and their children **following** in the flow of the document:

example

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.tabs {
  position: relative;
}
input {
  display: none;
}
.tabs .tab label {
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 2px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#check1:checked ~ .tabs label[for="check1"],
#check2:checked ~ .tabs label[for="check2"],
#check3:checked ~ .tabs label[for="check3"] {
  background-color: white;
  border-bottom: 0;
  padding: 4px 2px;
  top: 1px;
}
.contents {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
}
.contents .content {
  display: none;
  padding: 20px;
}
#check1:checked ~ .contents #tab1,
#check2:checked ~ .contents #tab2,
#check3:checked ~ .contents #tab3 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!-- begin hidden inputs for CSS tabs purpose -->
<input type="radio" name="ch" id="check1">
<input type="radio" name="ch" id="check2">
<input type="radio" name="ch" id="check3">
<!-- End hidden inputs for CSS tabs purpose -->
<div class="tabs">
  <span class="tab">
    <label for="check1">
      Tab 1
    </label>
  </span>
  <span class="tab">
    <label for="check2">
      Tab 2
    </label>
  </span>
  <span class="tab">
    <label for="check3">
      Tab 3
    </label>
  </span>
</div>
<div class="contents">
  <div class="content" id="tab1">Contenido 1</div>
  <div class="content" id="tab2"><strong>Contenido 2</strong>
  </div>
  <div class="content" id="tab3"><em>Contenido 3</em>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Really I was thinking in this solution too, but I was waiting for a solution for the exact problem. However, seems that this is the only solution to combine `:target` and `:checked`, and the behaviour is exactly what I need, so it's the correct answer.

Comment: A question: there's a way to make this without knowing the number of tabs that I have? With `:target` the advantage is that I don't need to know the number of tabs, so the app can grow up or down without changing the CSS.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude nop, unless you multiplicate numbers of rules from beginning (like 10 or maximum tab that it can be) or uses a preprocessor to generate x rules in a loop. Why don't you want to use target ?

Comment: I want to use target + checked, and if I can mix both of them, the tab system will be dynamic. I grow up the HTML but I don't need to write new CSS. So I'm interesting in the possibility of making it dynamic. If there aren't more choices, I will check this as the correct answer. Thank you!

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude you cannot use both because these two are two different things & technics and both have nothing to do with each other. on click or you check an input or you click a link :( ... Maybe you should read the specification on the W3C to find out uses and purpose of each. What you need is , then, to handle this behavior via javascript, which is a classic javascript job :)

Comment: Yeah, I am javascript developer, but I was trying with pure css to see the powerful of this language in simple functionalities, instead of load javascript for a task so simple. Maybe the best approach is use label with one onclick that changes the hash in the URL, but is not pure css. I will accept your answer. If in the future someone can suggest something, I can change it. Thanks again

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude If anythings comes up , ring me via a comment, i'll be as well curious and interest in any new suggestions.  Have fun on SO !

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is specified in [HTML5](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-label-element) (emphasis mine):

> The [activation behavior](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#activation-behavior) of a [`label`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-label-element) element for events
>   targeted at [interactive content](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#interactive-content-0) descendants of a [`label`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-label-element)
>   element, and any descendants of those [interactive content](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#interactive-content-0)
>   descendants, **must be to do nothing**.

Since the link is interactive content, clicking on it won't check the labeled radio input.

Comment: Thank you @Oriol. I didn't know that since my HTML it's valid in a HTML validator. Weird but true. Now I will not doing this kind of things never more. My upvote due the clear explanation. Thank you.